# Is it currently possible to create/model systems off of the ThermoPower Library in OpenModelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica

For a month now I've been trying to model Power Cycles, specifically the Brayton and Rankine Power Cycles, in an attempt to then model a Combined Power Cycle.

The Brayton Cycle example on the ThermoPower Library does in fact run and simulate. This has enabled me to correctly model my own model which also runs and simulates. But when it comes to the Rankine Power Cycle, the Library model always fails to run/simulate. I have also built MANY iterations of my own Rankine Power Cycle despite the Library model from working. All of my models also fail to run/simulate.

I have tried complex models and also very very simple models. All of my iterations fail. Also something worthy of noting, a lot of errors and translation errors occur with variables pertaining to pump.mo which are seemingly impossible to troubleshoot.

I have also been working off of the Master Branch of the ThermoPower Library with the most recent edits to the library. Still no successful runs/simulations of my own models as well as the Rankine Closed Loop Example off of the ThermoPower Library.

Working off of the ThermoPower Library since January has been a challenge. It seems most library examples/components have bugs in them preventing most examples from simulating. I've also been in contact with a builder of the ThermoPower library who has been telling me that the library is currently undergoing rebuilds.

So after experiencing/learning all of these factors, is it in fact possible to model systems off of the ThermoPower Library, or is it just my inability to model a system correctly?

Comment: Not familiar with this library, but are there example models for the "Rankine Power Cycle"? Do they work? Can you adapt those models? If they don't work, it sounds like the library _or_ the tool you are using would need a detailed bug report.

Comment: Hi @jrhodin , yes there are examples of this model within the ThermoPower Library. The Brayton Cycle is able to be simulated however the Rankine Cycle, along with multiple other examples pulled from that library fail to simulate correctly. 

I've tried many mannnny times to try and imitate/copy/replicate the Rankine Cycle myself. I've copied verbatim and also simplified models as much as possible but no simulations of mine have ever worked as well. I'm starting to think the whole library is very problematic but I only started using the software in January so I do not want to blame anyone.

Answer (score 2):

ThermoPower is tested by the OpenModelica team on their Jenkins server for every commit. You can see a summary of which examples run or not here:
https://libraries.openmodelica.org/branches/master/ThermoPower/ThermoPower.html

Please be aware that OpenModelica is working on a new frontend, it is tested here:
https://libraries.openmodelica.org/branches/newInst/ThermoPower/ThermoPower.html

You can also find an overview of ThermoPower related issues here:
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/wiki/CoverageIssues#ThermoPower

If you find new/additional issues, you should file an issue in either the OpenModelica issue tracker, or in the ThermoPower issue tracker (after searching of course):
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/report/1?sort=ticket&asc=0&page=1
https://github.com/casella/ThermoPower
But, I see, you already filed an issue, and received an answer there as well.